# Why appcenter analytics are not showing immediately on tracking events from android app?

Tags: android, azure-stream-analytics

I have an android app which is using appcenter analytics to track events. Sometimes the events shown immediately on appcenter website as soon as I performed tracked action. But at times, it takes longer time to show data on appcenter website, may be some longer hours or sometimes a day.

Answer (score 0):

is this question regarding Azure Stream Analytics? Please check your tags.